# What is the winged entity that Tikki produced?

Tags: miraculous-ladybug

In the
Season 4 episode 18 "Dearest Family," we see Tikki

> use her powers without a Miraculous holder to produce an enormous galette that threatens to cause havoc.

While doing so, she is enveloped in a column of pink light in which the image of a winged entity is visible.

[image]

What is the
nature of this winged entity? Is it Tikki's "human(oid) form," as some people have claimed? A shadow from some other object in the scene? An animation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of the fifth season strongly suggests that this is Tikki beginning to transform into her "true form" (or at least a much less cute and more awe-inspiring form), as we see when Tikki and Plagg are ordered to "reveal themselves" in the episode "Re-Creation":

[image: An image of Tikki in the process of revealing her other form, with pink light, a vague outline, and several wings.]

[image: Tikki in her other form. She resembles a humanoid ladybug with four black, insect-like arms, elytra, and a ring covered with glowing orbs behind her.]

Note that the image from the fourth season has the outline of Tikki's elytra and "dress," as well as diaphanous wings and a suggestion of arms.